# Android fragments strange load

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am making an 3 fragments scrollable app, left fragment is fragment1, fragment2 is in center, and fragment3 is on right side. I wanted to Fragment2(center) be the first to load, and i did that with mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
But when i start app i got this in logs.

```
            onStart Fragment1 
            onResume Fragment1
            onStart Fragment3
```

And Its onPause when i go to Fragment3(right). I want to be on Pause when i go to Fragment2(center) because  i got main exeption errors on Fragment3.

this is a MainActivity class

```
       public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {  


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;  
     ViewPager mViewPager;  


    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);  
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);


    }  


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {  
            super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();  
            switch (position) {  
            case 0:  
                return fragment = new Fragment1();  
            case 1:  
                return fragment = new Fragment2();  
            case 2:  
                return fragment = new Fragment3();  
            default:  
                break;  

            }  
            return fragment; 
        }


        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  

            return 3;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();  
            switch (position) {  
            case 0:  
                return getString(R.string.one).toUpperCase(l);  
            case 1:  
                return getString(R.string.two).toUpperCase(l);  
            case 2:  
                return getString(R.string.third).toUpperCase(l);  
            }  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  

     }
```

I am new to Android and i dont know how to fix this, any answer would help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using **FragmentPagerAdapter**, android by defaults loads a next and previous fragment in background, in order to load fragments efficiently and remove lag.

However they provide an API to customise the same and you may want to tweak it for better performance.

**setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)**, is used to set the number of extra fragments you would like to load in background. By default its set to 1.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Now you can not reduce it further, as per its design. That means ViewPager required you to load at least one page extra (before and after both) with the current page.

Try putting

**mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit (0)**, it will show the following warning:
"Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1"

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit (0) and 1, but didn't helped me, same like before, do you have any suggestion? because fragment1 and fragment3 is the json http objects, and when swiping app crashes.