# onCreateOptionsMenu of Fragment called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**Scenario:**
I using a ViewPager inside a Fragment. This ViewPager inflates 3 fragments (AFragment, BFragment, CFragment) pages using FragmentPagerAdapter.

I have printed logs inside
onCreateOptionsMenu 
onPrepareOptionsMenu 
of all 3 fragments.

**Problem:**

> For AFragment when created onCreateOptionsMenu was called only once,
>   but when I swiped to BFragment onCreateOptionsMenu and
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu  for BFragment were called twice. And similar
>   thing happened with CFragment.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and How I can avoid it?
Thanks.

Comment: Post your code here...

Answer (score 0):

Because android by defaults loads a next and previous fragment in background, in order to load fragments efficiently and to remove lag.

However you can customise the same  by using setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit), Which is used to set the number of extra fragments you would like to load in background. By default its set to 1.

Read [Android fragments strange load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753164/android-fragments-strange-load) for more information

Comment: By default it is one we can cant change so how can i solve my problem